# Is the random variable normal?

Tags: probability, self-study, normal-distribution

If X is a continuous random variable and P(X<=-a) = P(X>=a), is it possible to conclude that the random variable is normal?

If yes how?

Thank you

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: There are countless random variables satisfying this condition.  Consider any distribution that is symmetric about $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Imagine a truncated normal distribution, it would still fulfill these criteria and would not be normal.

Comment: Thanks! Just another question if Y =X^2 any you give me hint on how to find the density of Y?

Comment: I am stuck at the point P(Y<=y) = P(X<=√y) -P(X<= -√y)

Comment: Please open another question, I would suggest the delta distribution method https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities#Derivation_using_the_Delta_Distribution